# Enforce type difference

Tags: scala, types

In Scala I can enforce type equality at compile time. For example:

```
case class Foo[A,B]( a: A, b: B )( implicit ev: A =:= B )

scala> Foo( 1, 2 )
res3: Foo[Int,Int] = Foo(1,2)

scala> Foo( 1, "2" )
<console>:10: error: Cannot prove that Int =:= java.lang.String.
```

Is there a way to enforce that type A and type B should be different ?

Comment: Nice one… But does it have useful applications? Sounds like something like [Miles Sabin's magical typesystem tricks](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) could maybe be of use.

Comment: @Jean-Phillipe_Pellet: I would like to make a bidirectional map of types [A,B], when I call apply with A, it returns a B, and when I call apply with B it returns an A. I don't know if it will be possible, but at least I need to different types.

Comment: I see. Mightn't you want to name the two accessor methods differently then, to allow for the same type parameters?

Comment: That would be plan B, if I cannot find a way to implement the fist idea.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that something along the lines of `implicit def t[N, A >: N, B >: N]()(implicit n: N =:= Nothing) = new =/=[A,B]` would work (expressing "if the closest common subtype of A and B is Nothing, they are different"), but it doesn't...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Riffing off of Jean-Philippe's ideas, this works:

```
sealed class =!=[A,B]

trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def equal[A]: =!=[A, A] = sys.error("should not be called")
}
object =!= extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def nequal[A,B](implicit same: A =:= B = null): =!=[A,B] = 
    if (same != null) sys.error("should not be called explicitly with same type")
    else new =!=[A,B]
}     

case class Foo[A,B](a: A, b: B)(implicit e: A =!= B)
```

Then:

```
// compiles:
Foo(1f, 1.0)
Foo("", 1.0)
Foo("", 1)
Foo("Fish", Some("Fish"))

// doesn't compile
// Foo(1f, 1f)
// Foo("", "")
```

I'd probably simplify this as follows, since the checks for "cheating" can always be circumvented anyway (e.g. `Foo(1, 1)(null)` or `=!=.nequal(null)`):

```
sealed class =!=[A,B]

trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  /** do not call explicitly! */
  implicit def equal[A]: =!=[A, A] = sys.error("should not be called")
}
object =!= extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  /** do not call explicitly! */
  implicit def nequal[A,B]: =!=[A,B] = new =!=[A,B]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've found something similar in a blog comment, but unfortunately, the check happens at runtime not at compilation.

Comment: @paradigmatic I'm not sure whether I'm interpreting your comment correctly....  In my code the check happens at compile-time -- did you mean that the blog comment demonstrates a runtime check?

Comment: My bad. Your solution works perfectly ! I've understood the difference with what I've seen. I checked it with subtypes and it also works well.

Comment: @paradigmatic Updated with a simpler version that eliminates the "cheating" checks.  As explained in the answer, those checks can always be circumvented anyway.

Comment: @Aaron Nice simplification. You could declare `sealed class =!=[A,B] extends NotNull` to prevent nasty users from manually passing `null`.  Similarly, we could have a `NotNull` subclass of `=:=` to enforce the cheating check in your first version. The last thing we cannot prevent is a manual call to `equal`…

Comment: Hmm… Forget about the `NotNull` subclass of `=:=`…

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is the simplest one. I don't really care about making "idiot"-proof, because I fear idiots will always find a solution to circumvent it...

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work with the use case `def foo[T](implicit ev: T =!= Nothing): T`

Comment: @sourcedelica works for me in Scala 2.9.1. `foo` (with no type argument) results in a compile error, while `foo[String]` compiles and runs without incident.

Comment: @sourcedelica Although curiously it doesn't seem to work if the parameter is already bound as in `class C[T](v: T) { def foo[T](implicit ev: T =!= Nothing) = v }`. In this example, `new C("a").foo[String]` compiles but `new C("a").foo` does not.

Comment: @sourcedelica Nevermind, that was just me being dumb. `class C[T](v: T) { def foo(implicit ev: T =!= Nothing) = v }` works just fine.

Comment: @AaronNovstrup `def foo[A](implicit e: A =!= Nothing) = ???` doesn't seem to work in scala 2.10.3

Comment: @mikea Not sure what you mean. With that definition, calling `foo[Nothing]` or just `foo` results in a compile-time error (as desired), and calling `foo[String]` results in a run-time error (because you've provided no method body). That's exactly what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 57):

I have a simpler solution, which also leverages ambiguity,

```
trait =!=[A, B]

implicit def neq[A, B] : A =!= B = null

// This pair excludes the A =:= B case
implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =!= A = null
implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =!= A = null
```

The original use case,

```
case class Foo[A,B](a : A, b : B)(implicit ev: A =!= B)
new Foo(1, "1")
new Foo("foo", Some("foo"))

// These don't compile
// new Foo(1, 1)
// new Foo("foo", "foo")
// new Foo(Some("foo"), Some("foo"))
```

**Update**

We can relate this to my ["magical typesystem tricks"](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/) (thanks @jpp ;-) as follows,

```
type ¬[T] = T => Nothing
implicit def neg[T, U](t : T)(implicit ev : T =!= U) : ¬[U] = null

def notString[T <% ¬[String]](t : T) = t
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> val ns1 = notString(1)
ns1: Int = 1

scala> val ns2 = notString(1.0)
ns2: Double = 1.0

scala> val ns3 = notString(Some("foo"))
ns3: Some[java.lang.String] = Some(foo)

scala> val ns4 = notString("foo")
<console>:14: error: No implicit view available from 
  java.lang.String => (String) => Nothing.
       val ns4 = notString2("foo")
                            ^
```

Comment: Nice! It's probably worth pointing out that, as with the other answers, this implements negation-as-failure: `notString("foo": AnyRef)` compiles.

Comment: @Aaron this technique, and indeed the question, only makes sense in a static context. Otherwise there'd be no other option than to do dynamic runtime type tests.

Comment: @Miles I wondered if there was a way to statically enforce a stronger notion of inequality, where the static constraint indicates that any two instances of the types have different runtime types. For example, String and Int are unequal in this sense, while String and AnyRef are not. `String with Int` would seem to be a contradiction, but, if my understanding is correct, it's not instantiable.

Comment: @Aaron not entirely sure what you mean, but relatedly it's possible to define a type operator A <:!< B which states that A is not a subtype of B (ie. it's the opposite of A <:< B from predef).

Comment: @Miles Suppose I want to define `=!=` so that `A =!= B` if and only if every non-null instance of `A` is not an instance of `B` and every non-null instance of `B` is not an instance of `A`.  By this definition, `String =!= Int`. My intuition is that the compiler has the information to enforce the constraint, but that it's not expressible in Scala.

Comment: Note that `A =!= B` is not equivalent to `A <:!< B AND B <:!< A`. Consider definitions `class A`, `class B`, and `trait T`. Then `A =!= B`, but *not* `A =!= T` since `new A with T` is an instance of both `A` and `T`.

Comment: this solution works for `A =!= Nothing` while @AaronNovstrup's doesn't.

Comment: @mikea Actually, mine does (at least in 2.9.1, 2.10.0, and 2.10.3).

Comment: Nice solution but can we get a better error, such as `Types (A, B) do not confirm to A =!= B]`?

Answer (score 19):

I liked the simplicity and effectiveness of Miles Sabin's first solution, but was a bit dissatisfied with the fact that the error we get is not very helpful:

By example with the following definition:

```
def f[T]( implicit e: T =!= String ) {}
```

Attemtping to do `f[String]` will fail to compile with:

```
<console>:10: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method neqAmbig1 in object =!= of type [A]=> =!=[A,A]
 and method neqAmbig2 in object =!= of type [A]=> =!=[A,A]
 match expected type =!=[String,String]
              f[String]
               ^
```

I'd rather have the compiler tell me something along the line of "T is not different from String"
It turns out that it's quite easy if add yet another level of implicits in such a way that we turn the *ambiguity* error
into an *implicit not found* error. From then we can use the `implicitNotFound` annotation to emit a custom error message:

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${A} =!= ${B}.")
trait =!=[A,B]
object =!= {
  class Impl[A, B]
  object Impl {
    implicit def neq[A, B] : A Impl B = null
    implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A Impl A = null
    implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A Impl A = null
  }

  implicit def foo[A,B]( implicit e: A Impl B ): A =!= B = null
}
```

Now let's try to call `f[String]`:

```
scala> f[String]
<console>:10: error: Cannot prove that String =!= String.
              f[String]
           ^
```

That's better. Thanks compiler.

As a last trick for those that like the context bound syntactic sugar, one can define this alias (based on type lambdas):

```
type IsNot[A] = { type λ[B] = A =!= B }
```

Then we can define `f` like this:

```
def f[T:IsNot[String]#λ] {}
```

Whether it is easier to read is highly subjective. In any case is definitly shorter than writing the full implicit parameter list.

**UPDATE**: For completeness, here the equivalent code for expressing that `A` is is not a sub-type of `B`:

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${A} <:!< ${B}.")
trait <:!<[A,B]
object <:!< {
  class Impl[A, B]
  object Impl {
    implicit def nsub[A, B] : A Impl B = null
    implicit def nsubAmbig1[A, B>:A] : A Impl B = null
    implicit def nsubAmbig2[A, B>:A] : A Impl B = null
  }

  implicit def foo[A,B]( implicit e: A Impl B ): A <:!< B = null
}

type IsNotSub[B] = { type λ[A] = A <:!< B }
```

And for expressing that `A` is not convertible to `B` :

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${A} <%!< ${B}.")
trait <%!<[A,B]
object <%!< {
  class Impl[A, B]
  object Impl {
    implicit def nconv[A, B] : A Impl B = null
    implicit def nconvAmbig1[A<%B, B] : A Impl B = null
    implicit def nconvAmbig2[A<%B, B] : A Impl B = null
  }

  implicit def foo[A,B]( implicit e: A Impl B ): A <%!< B = null
}

type IsNotView[B] = { type λ[A] = A <%!< B }
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Just got this working on Scala 2.12 in 2021.

Comment: I was trying to prevent Futures from being passed into my timing method, here's the signature: `def time[T:IsNotSub[Future[Any]]#λ](reporting: Double => Unit, block: => T)`

Comment: Nice. Though arguably in this case you might want to just handle the future as a special case instead of outright forbidding futures to be passed (with a separate overload) and take the end time once the future completes.

Answer (score 9):

Based on [Landei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375232/landei)'s idea, the following seems to work:

```
case class Foo[A, B <: A, C <: A]( a: B, b: C)(implicit f: AnyVal <:< A)

scala> Foo(1f, 1.0)
res75: Foo[AnyVal,Float,Double] = Foo(1.0,1.0)

scala> Foo("", 1.0)
res76: Foo[Any,java.lang.String,Double] = Foo(,1.0)

scala> Foo(1f, 1f)
<console>:10: error: Cannot prove that AnyVal <:< Float.
       Foo(1f, 1f)
          ^

scala> Foo("", "")
<console>:10: error: Cannot prove that AnyVal <:< java.lang.String.
       Foo("", "")
          ^

scala> Foo("", 1)
res79: Foo[Any,java.lang.String,Int] = Foo(,1)
```

Comment: Nice trick!  But this only works for primitive types, and only because the hierarchy is flat there.  This does not work:  `Foo("Fish",Some("Fish"))`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another attempt:

```
class =!=[A, B] private () extends NotNull

object =!= {
  implicit def notMeantToBeCalled1[A, B >: A, C >: B <: A]: =!=[B, A] = error("should not be called")
  implicit def notMeantToBeCalled2[A, B >: A, C >: B <: A]: =!=[B, A] = error("should not be called")
  implicit def unambigouslyDifferent[A, B](implicit same: A =:= B = null): =!=[A, B] =
    if (same != null) error("should not be called explicitly with the same type")
    else new =!=
}

case class Foo[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =!= B)
```

Then, again:

```
// compiles:
Foo(1f, 1.0)
Foo("", 1.0)
Foo("", 1)
Foo("Fish", Some("Fish"))

// doesn't compile
// Foo(1f, 1f)
// Foo("", "")
```

Like in my other proposal, the aim here is to introduce a compile-time ambiguity when `A` and `B` are the same. Here, we provide two implicits for the case where `A` is the same as `B`, and an unambiguous implicit when this is not the case.

Note that the problem is that you could still explicitly provide the implicit parameter by manually calling `=!=.notMeantToBeCalled1` or `=!=.unambigouslyDifferent`. I couldn't think of a way to prevent this at compile time. However, we can throw an exception at runtime, with the trick that `unambigouslyDifferent` requires an evidence parameter itself indicating whether `A` is the same as `B`. But wait... Aren't we trying to prove the exact opposite? Yes, and that's why that `same` implicit parameter has a default value of `null`. And we expect it to be `null` for all legal uses — the only time where it would not be `null` is when a nasty user calls e.g. `Foo(1f, 1f)(=:=.unambiguouslyDifferent[Float, Float])`, and there we can prevent this cheating by throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm not sure the cheating checks are worth the additional complexity -- especially since the nasty user can still call `=!=.unambiguoslyDifferent[Float, Float](null)`, or, since `=!=` is just a phantom type, `Foo(1, 1)(null)`.  It *would* be nice if Scala had some way to express that an implicit method can not be called explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this, then?

```
class Foo[A, B] private (a: A, b: B)

object Foo {
  def apply[A, B <: A, C >: A <: B](a: A, b: B)(implicit nothing: Nothing) = nothing
  def apply[A, B >: A, C >: B <: A](a: A, b: B)(implicit nothing: Nothing, dummy: DummyImplicit) = nothing
  def apply[A, B](a: A, b: B): Foo[A, B] = new Foo(a, b)
}
```

Then:

```
// compiles:
Foo(1f, 1.0)
Foo("", 1.0)
Foo("", 1)
Foo("Fish", Some("Fish"))

// doesn't compile
// Foo(1f, 1f)
// Foo("", "")
```

The idea is to make resolution ambiguous when `A`is the same as `B`, and unambiguous when they are not the same. To further emphasize that the ambiguous methods should not be called, I added an implicit of type `Nothing`, which should never be around (and should certainly look wrong to the caller if they try to insert one explicitly). (The role of the `DummyImplicit` is just to give a different signature to the first two methods.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just the beginnings of what I could think is an answer. The code below will return either an `Yes` or an `No` depending on whether the types are equal or not, if you ask for `implicitly[AreEqual[A,B]]`. How to go from there to actually making a check I haven't been able to figure out. Maybe the whole approach is doomed, maybe someone can make something out of it. Mind you, `implicitly[No[A, B]]` will *always* return something, one can't use that. :-(

```
class AreEqual[A, B]
trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def toNo[A : Manifest, B : Manifest]: No[A, B] = No[A, B]
}
object AreEqual extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def toYes[A, B](implicit ev: A =:= B, m1: Manifest[A], m2: Manifest[B]): Yes[A, B] = Yes[A, B]
}

case class Yes[A : Manifest, B : Manifest]() extends AreEqual[A, B] {
  override def toString: String = "Yes(%s, %s)" format (manifest[A].toString, manifest[B].toString)
}
case class No[A : Manifest, B : Manifest]() extends AreEqual[A, B] {
  override def toString: String = "No(%s, %s)" format (manifest[A].toString, manifest[B].toString)
}
```

Test:

```
scala> implicitly[AreEqual[String, Option[String]]]
res0: AreEqual[String,Option[String]] = No(java.lang.String, scala.Option[java.lang.String])

scala> implicitly[AreEqual[String, String]]
res1: AreEqual[String,String] = Yes(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```