# Type constraint for type inequality in scala

Tags: scala, type-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enforce type difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference)

Since there is a generalized type constraint enforcing equality in scala `=:=`, is there one that enforces "not equals" for types? Basically `!=` but for types?

**Edit**

Comment below points to an existing [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference) and the answer seems to be that (1) no, it's not in the standard library (2) yes, it's possible to define one.

So I'll modify my question because of a thought that occurred to me after I saw the answer.

Given the existing solution:

```
sealed class =!=[A,B]

trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def equal[A]: =!=[A, A] = sys.error("should not be called")
}
object =!= extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def nequal[A,B](implicit same: A =:= B = null): =!=[A,B] = 
    if (same != null) sys.error("should not be called explicitly with same type")
    else new =!=[A,B]
}     

case class Foo[A,B](a: A, b: B)(implicit e: A =!= B)
```

If `A <: B` or `A >: B`, will it still be the case that `A =!= B`? If not, is it possible to modify the solution such that if `A =!= B` then it is not the case that `A <: B` or `A >: B`?

Comment: The SO devs should *really* fix their broken search so that looking for `=!=` actually lists that question. That bug has been known for 4 years now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) defines the type operator `A <:!< B` (meaning `A` is not a subtype of `B`) using the same implicit ambiguity trick that's used for strict type inequality,

```
trait <:!<[A, B]

implicit def nsub[A, B] : A <:!< B = new <:!<[A, B] {}
implicit def nsubAmbig1[A, B >: A] : A <:!< B = sys.error("Unexpected call")
implicit def nsubAmbig2[A, B >: A] : A <:!< B = sys.error("Unexpected call")
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> import shapeless.TypeOperators._
import shapeless.TypeOperators._

scala> implicitly[Int <:!< String]
res0: shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[Int,String] =
  shapeless.TypeOperators$$anon$2@200fde5c

scala> implicitly[Int <:!< Int]
<console>:11: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 in object TypeOperators of type
   [A, B >: A]=> shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[A,B]
 and method nsubAmbig2 in object TypeOperators of type
   [A, B >: A]=> shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[A,B]
 match expected type shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[Int,Int]
              implicitly[Int <:!< Int]
                        ^

scala> class Foo ; class Bar extends Foo
defined class Foo
defined class Bar

scala> implicitly[Foo <:!< Bar]
res2: shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[Foo,Bar] =
  shapeless.TypeOperators$$anon$2@871f548

scala> implicitly[Bar <:!< Foo]
<console>:13: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 in object TypeOperators of type
   [A, B >: A]=> shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[A,B]
 and method nsubAmbig2 in object TypeOperators of type
   [A, B >: A]=> shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[A,B]
 match expected type shapeless.TypeOperators.<:!<[Bar,Foo]
              implicitly[Bar <:!< Foo]
                        ^
```

Comment: Is there away to get this to work with higher kinded types?
Something like
type A[+T]
implicitly[A[T]<:!<Iterable[T]]

Comment: Sorry, it appears my issue was not with higher kinded types, but when you mixin trait {type A[+T] = Iterable[T]} it manages to compile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591466/scala-mixin-type-constraints-still-compiles