# scala - Mixin type constraints still compiles

Tags: scala, types

following on from 
[Enforce type difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference)

I've noticed this compiles and am not sure why.

```
trait NotFuture {

  type Out[+T]

  implicitly[Out[_] =!= scala.concurrent.Future[_]]
}

val newNotFuture = new NotFuture {
  type Out[+T] = scala.concurrent.Future[T]
}
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to construct the required inequality proof until `Out` is actually defined. The closest I can get to what you want is something like this,

```
scala> import shapeless._ // for =:!=
import shapeless._

scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> trait NotFuture {
     |   type Out[+T]
     |   val ev: Out[_] =:!= Future[_]
     |   def prf(implicit ev: Out[_] =:!= Future[_]) = ev
     | }
defined trait NotFuture

scala> val nf = new NotFuture { type Out[+T] = List[T] ; val ev = prf }
nf: NotFuture{type Out[+T] = List[T]} = $anon$1@5723cc36

scala> val nf = new NotFuture { type Out[+T] = Future[T] ; val ev = prf }
<console>:12: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method neqAmbig1 in package shapeless of type [A]=> shapeless.=:!=[A,A]
 and method neqAmbig2 in package shapeless of type [A]=> shapeless.=:!=[A,A]
 match expected type shapeless.=:!=[this.Out[_],scala.concurrent.Future[_]]
       val nf = new NotFuture { type Out[+T] = Future[T] ; val ev = prf }
```

Notice that providing the proof is mandatory (because `ev` is abstract in `NotFuture`) and provided semi-implicitly in the subclasses (`val ev = prf`).

Comment: Cheers for that. Ill see if I can work it in to solve my problem