# Scala: are generalised type constraints "type operators"?

Tags: scala, type-constraints, higher-kinded-types, type-level-computation, path-dependent-type

I have the following Peano formulation of natural numbers at the type level: [gist](https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/37cd6f72d39b29da5366201a3f32ecec)

with the natural number's type having the following interface:

```
sealed trait NaturalNumber {
  type MatchZero[T <: Up, F[_ <: NaturalNumber] <: Up, Up] <: Up
  type Compare[N <: NaturalNumber] <: Comparison
}
```

I use it in my code in this form:

```
def getResource(manifest: ResourceManifest)(maj: VersionNumber, min: VersionNumber)
          (implicit
           maj_check: (maj.Nat)#Compare[manifest.Major]#eq =:= True,
           min_check: (min.Nat)#Compare[manifest.Minor]#le =:= True
) = manifest.getResource
```

which is not very readable. I would like to define "type operators": `IsEqual` and `IsLessEqual` similar to `=:=` and `<:<` for my version checks so that I can have:

```
def getResource(manifest: ResourceManifest)(maj: VersionNumber, min: VersionNumber)
          (implicit
           maj_check: maj.Nat IsEqual manifest.Major,
           min_check: min.Nat IsLessOrEqual manifest.Minor) = manifest.getResource
```

can I do that? could you provide an implementation?

I find the implementation of `=:=` and `>:>` a bit complicated but they don't look like they are anything special. In fact, I have seen a similar type inequality enforcement [construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135293/type-constraint-for-type-inequality-in-scala). Can I think of them as type operators? if so, can I write other type operators based on existing type operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define [higher-kinded types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/higher-kinded-types?sort=votes)

```
type IsEqual[N <: NaturalNumber, M <: NaturalNumber] = N#Compare[M]#eq =:= True
type IsLessOrEqual[N <: NaturalNumber, M <: NaturalNumber] = N#Compare[M]#eq =:= True
```

and use them

```
def getResource(manifest: ResourceManifest)(maj: VersionNumber, min: VersionNumber)
               (implicit
                maj_check: maj.Nat IsEqual manifest.Major,
                min_check: min.Nat IsLessOrEqual manifest.Minor) = manifest.getResource
```