# Using context bounds "negatively" to ensure type class instance is absent from scope

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, scalaz, higher-kinded-types

**tl;dr**: How do I do something like the made up code below:

```scala
def notFunctor[M[_] : Not[Functor]](m: M[_]) = s"$m is not a functor"
```

The '`Not[Functor]`', being the made up part here.
I want it to succeed when the 'm' provided is not a Functor, and fail the compiler otherwise.

**Solved**: skip the rest of the question and go right ahead to the answer below.

---

What I'm trying to accomplish is, roughly speaking, "negative evidence".

Pseudo code would look something like so:

```scala
// type class for obtaining serialization size in bytes.
trait SizeOf[A] { def sizeOf(a: A): Long }

// type class specialized for types whose size may vary between instances
trait VarSizeOf[A] extends SizeOf[A]

// type class specialized for types whose elements share the same size (e.g. Int)
trait FixedSizeOf[A] extends SizeOf[A] {
  def fixedSize: Long
  def sizeOf(a: A) = fixedSize
}

// SizeOf for container with fixed-sized elements and Length (using scalaz.Length)
implicit def fixedSizeOf[T[_] : Length, A : FixedSizeOf] = new VarSizeOf[T[A]] {
  def sizeOf(as: T[A]) = ... // length(as) * sizeOf[A]
}

// SizeOf for container with scalaz.Foldable, and elements with VarSizeOf
implicit def foldSizeOf[T[_] : Foldable, A : SizeOf] = new VarSizeOf[T[A]] {
  def sizeOf(as: T[A]) = ... // foldMap(a => sizeOf(a))
}
```

Keep in mind that `fixedSizeOf()` is preferable where relevant, since it saves us the traversal over the collection.

This way, for container types where only `Length` is defined (but not `Foldable`), and for elements where a `FixedSizeOf` is defined, we get improved performance.

For the rest of the cases, we go over the collection and sum individual sizes.

My problem is in the cases where both `Length` and `Foldable` are defined for the container, and `FixedSizeOf` is defined for the elements. This is a very common case here (e.g.,: `List[Int]` has both defined).

Example:

```scala
scala> implicitly[SizeOf[List[Int]]].sizeOf(List(1,2,3))
<console>:24: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method foldSizeOf of type [T[_], A](implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Foldable[T], implicit evidence$2: SizeOf[A])VarSizeOf[T[A]]
 and method fixedSizeOf of type [T[_], A](implicit evidence$1: scalaz.Length[T], implicit evidence$2: FixedSizeOf[A])VarSizeOf[T[A]]
 match expected type SizeOf[List[Int]]
              implicitly[SizeOf[List[Int]]].sizeOf(List(1,2,3))
```

What I would like is to be able to rely on the `Foldable` type class only when the `Length`+`FixedSizeOf` combination does not apply.

For that purpose, I can change the definition of `foldSizeOf()` to accept `VarSizeOf` elements:

```scala
implicit def foldSizeOfVar[T[_] : Foldable, A : VarSizeOf] = // ...
```

And now we have to fill in the problematic part that covers `Foldable` containers with `FixedSizeOf` elements and *no `Length` defined*. I'm not sure how to approach this, but pseudo-code would look something like:

```scala
implicit def foldSizeOfFixed[T[_] : Foldable : Not[Length], A : FixedSizeOf] = // ...
```

The '`Not[Length]`', obviously, being the made up part here.

**Partial solutions I am aware of**

1) Define a class for low priority implicits and extend it, as seen in '`object Predef extends LowPriorityImplicits`'.
The last implicit (`foldSizeOfFixed()`) can be defined in the parent class, and will be overridden by alternative from the descendant class.

I am not interested in this option because I'd like to eventually be able to support recursive usage of `SizeOf`, and this will prevent the implicit in the low priority base class from relying on those in the sub class (is my understanding here correct? EDIT: wrong! implicit lookup works from the context of the sub class, this is a viable solution!)

2) A rougher approach is relying on `Option[TypeClass]` (e.g.,: `Option[Length[List]]`. A few of those and I can just write one big ol' implicit that picks `Foldable` and `SizeOf` as mandatory and `Length` and `FixedSizeOf` as optional, and relies on the latter if they are available. (source: [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8773))

The two problems here are lack of modularity and falling back to runtime exceptions when no relevant type class instances can be located (this example can probably be made to work with this solution, but that's not always possible)

EDIT: This is the best I was able to get with optional implicits. It's not there yet:

```scala
implicit def optionalTypeClass[TC](implicit tc: TC = null) = Option(tc)
type OptionalLength[T[_]] = Option[Length[T]]
type OptionalFixedSizeOf[T[_]] = Option[FixedSizeOf[T]]

implicit def sizeOfContainer[
    T[_] : Foldable : OptionalLength,
    A : SizeOf : OptionalFixedSizeOf]: SizeOf[T[A]] = new SizeOf[T[A]] {
  def sizeOf(as: T[A]) = {

    // optionally calculate using Length + FixedSizeOf is possible
    val fixedLength = for {
      lengthOf <- implicitly[OptionalLength[T]]
      sizeOf <- implicitly[OptionalFixedSizeOf[A]]
    } yield lengthOf.length(as) * sizeOf.fixedSize

    // otherwise fall back to Foldable
    fixedLength.getOrElse { 
      val foldable = implicitly[Foldable[T]]
      val sizeOf = implicitly[SizeOf[A]]
      foldable.foldMap(as)(a => sizeOf.sizeOf(a))
    }
  }
}
```

Except this collides with `fixedSizeOf()` from earlier, which is still necessary.

Thanks for any help or perspective :-)

Comment: Option #1 above (the one with implicit priorities) will work. I'm still interested in something more elegant, so the question remains open for now.

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate [the negation trick (miles answer, update)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference/6944070#6944070)

Comment: The negation trick could probably be made to work here, but I think prioritization is by far the more desirable solution in this situation.

Comment: I added an answer, then re-read the question and realised I'd missed a vital part, so deleted it.

Comment: Absense of evidence is not evidence of absence!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I eventually solved this using an ambiguity-based solution that doesn't require prioritizing using inheritance.

Here is my attempt at generalizing this.

We use the type `Not[A]` to construct negative type classes:

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Not[A]

trait Monoid[_] // or import scalaz._, Scalaz._
type NotMonoid[A] = Not[Monoid[A]] 

trait Functor[_[_]] // or import scalaz._, Scalaz._
type NotFunctor[M[_]] = Not[Functor[M]]
```

...which can then be used as context bounds:

```scala
def foo[T: NotMonoid] = ...
```

We proceed by ensuring that every valid expression of Not[A] will gain at least one implicit instance.

```scala
implicit def notA[A, TC[_]] = new Not[TC[A]] {}
```

The instance is called 'notA' -- 'not' because if it is the only instance found for 'Not[TC[A]]' then the negative type class is found to apply; the 'A' is commonly appended for methods that deal with flat-shaped types (e.g. Int).

We now introduce an ambiguity to turn away cases where the undesired type class *is* applied:

```scala
implicit def notNotA[A : TC, TC[_]] = new Not[TC[A]] {}
```

This is almost exactly the same as 'NotA', except here we are only interested in types for which an instance of the type class specified by 'TC' exists in implicit scope. The instance is named 'notNotA', since by merely matching the implicit being looked up, it will create an ambiguity with 'notA', failing the implicit search (which is our goal).

Let's go over a usage example. We'll use the 'NotMonoid' negative type class from above:

```scala
implicitly[NotMonoid[java.io.File]] // succeeds
implicitly[NotMonoid[Int]] // fails

def showIfNotMonoid[A: NotMonoid](a: A) = a.toString

showIfNotMonoid(3) // fails, good!
showIfNotMonoid(scala.Console) // succeeds for anything that isn't a Monoid
```

So far so good! However, types shaped M[_] and type classes shaped TC[_[_]] aren't supported yet by the scheme above. Let's add implicits for them as well:

```scala
implicit def notM[M[_], TC[_[_]]] = new Not[TC[M]] {}
implicit def notNotM[M[_] : TC, TC[_[_]]] = new Not[TC[M]] {}

implicitly[NotFunctor[List]] // fails
implicitly[NotFunctor[Class]] // succeeds
```

Simple enough. Note that Scalaz has a workaround for the boilerplate resulting from dealing with several type shapes -- look for 'Unapply'. I haven't been able to make use of it for the basic case (type class of shape TC[_], such as Monoid), even though it worked on TC[_[_]] (e.g. Functor) like a charm, so this answer doesn't cover that.

If anybody's interested, here's everything needed in a single snippet:

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Not[A]

object Not {
  implicit def notA[A, TC[_]] = new Not[TC[A]] {}
  implicit def notNotA[A : TC, TC[_]] = new Not[TC[A]] {}

  implicit def notM[M[_], TC[_[_]]] = new Not[TC[M]] {}
  implicit def notNotM[M[_] : TC, TC[_[_]]] = new Not[TC[M]] {}
}

import Not._

type NotNumeric[A] = Not[Numeric[A]]
implicitly[NotNumeric[String]] // succeeds
implicitly[NotNumeric[Int]] // fails
```

and the pseudo code I asked for in the question would look like so (actual code):

```scala
// NotFunctor[M[_]] declared above
def notFunctor[M[_] : NotFunctor](m: M[_]) = s"$m is not a functor"
```

**Update:** Similar technique applied to implicit conversions:

```scala
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Not[A]

object Not {
  implicit def not[V[_], A](a: A) = new Not[V[A]] {}
  implicit def notNot[V[_], A <% V[A]](a: A) = new Not[V[A]] {}
}
```

We can now (e.g.) define a function that will only admit values if their types aren't viewable as Ordered:

```scala
def unordered[A <% Not[Ordered[A]]](a: A) = a
```

Comment: The previous solution I posted used the 'HasNo[M[\_], TC[\_[\_]]]' binary type constructor (used infix: 'List HasNo Functor'), but expanding that to support 'A' and 'TC[\_]' seemed impossible without introducing a new identifier. I eventually settled for the 'Not[A]' type above, and used several implicits to unapply the 'A' into it's components (either M[\_] and TC[\_[\_]] or A and TC[\_]).

Comment: Although I like when compiler detects most of errors and/or early decides about algorithm branches to take, and even if I actually agree with you about that this surely can be handy - it still is a .. candy. Most of people will probably take an easier route. Be careful not to be accused of http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MentalMasturbation ;-) Good job! Keep on! ;-)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Is there a StackOverflow badge for that?

Comment: Apparently not, no well defined rules, people would need to vote on that:) There are some badges for answering your own questions though, I think they are the closest, as if solving own problem that noone wanted to dig in? Not sure though.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Joking aside, is your skepticism aimed at type-level programming in general? My use case is serialization, and having the compiler figure out the best serialization strategy for an object is majorly beneficial.

Comment: Not skeptical, just bitter a bit. I like C2 Wiki and recently seen that MM article, loosely related to the general idea that ThinkingHurts. Of course MM means an extreme and unnecessary code complication, which certainly does not apply here, but I know many not-novice programmers that would describe your job as exactly as such. I tend to limit myself in creating tools like this and striving to make them simple and well explained, yet I'm hearing that guy X or Y don't like to work with me because "I force them to think":) I fully agree/congrat/thank/+1/ack your work! GJ/KeepOn were serious:)

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 3 (aka Dotty), the aforementioned tricks no longer work.
[The negation of givens is built-in](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/givens.html#negated-givens) with `NotGiven`:

```
def f[T](value: T)(using ev: NotGiven[MyTypeclass[T]])
```

Examples:

```
f("ok") // no given instance of MyTypeclass[T] in scope
```

```
given MyTypeclass[String] = ... // provide the typeclass
f("bad") // compile error
```