# How to trick Scala to not find duplicate implicits for Nothing

Tags: scala, type-systems, shapeless

I am trying to use the typeclass pattern in Scala to mark all the valid API serializable types, so that we can have compile-time safety around what we serialize. Our underlying library accepts an `AnyRef` which can lead to weird errors when not explicitly declaring the type before serializing it.

We allow sending out a public model, an iterable of public models, an option of public model, or a unit.

```
trait PublicModel
case class UserModel(name: String) extends PublicModel
sealed class SafeForPublic[-T]
implicit object PublicModelOk extends SafeForPublic[PublicModel]
implicit object IterablePublicModelOk extends SafeForPublic[Iterable[PublicModel]]
implicit object OptionPublicModelOk extends SafeForPublic[Option[PublicModel]]
implicit object UnitOk extends SafeForPublic[Unit]
```

This method works well for everything except methods where the parameter type is an option. This is because `None` is an `Option[Nothing]`, so `T = Nothing` which will tell the compiler to look up an implicit object of type `SafeForPublic[Nothing]` and it will find both `SafeForPublic[PublicModel]` as well as `SafeForPublic[Iterable[PublicModel]]`

```
def boxed[T : SafeForPublic](t: Option[T]) = println("wooohoo!")

boxed(Some(None))  // works
boxed(Some(1))  // doesn't compile. Int is not a valid serializable model.
boxed(Some({}))  // works
boxed(Some(UserModel("ok")))  // works
boxed(Some(Seq(UserModel("ok"))))  // works
boxed(None) // doesn't compile, duplicate implicits ><
```

Any idea how I can trick the compiler to not find duplicate implicits for `Nothing`. I saw Miles Sabin had a trick using:

```
sealed trait NotNothing[A]{
  type B
}
object NotNothing {
  implicit val nothing = new NotNothing[Nothing]{ type B = Any }
  implicit def notNothing[A] = new NotNothing[A]{ type B = A }
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to use it. Halp?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962743/using-context-bounds-negatively-to-ensure-type-class-instance-is-absent-from-s) for a walkthrough of the negation trick. I ended up with a generic "Not[_]" type class. See the answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to some help from the Scala IRC channel, I figured out that LowPriority implicits was created to solve this issue.

I used this to fix it:

```
sealed class SafeForPublic[-T]
trait LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit object PublicModelOk extends SafeForPublic[PublicModel]
  implicit object IterablePublicModelOk extends SafeForPublic[Iterable[PublicModel]]
  implicit object OptionPublicModelOk extends SafeForPublic[Option[PublicModel]]
  implicit object UnitOk extends SafeForPublic[Unit]
}
object Implicits extends LowPriorityImplicits {
  implicit object NothingOk extends SafeForPublic[Nothing]
}
import Implicits._
def boxed[T : SafeForPublic](t: Option[T]) = println("woohoo!")
boxed(None) // compiles! \o/
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this solution works? I guess the name `LowPriorityImplicits` is not somehow special, but this is also not clear from your answer.

Comment: @ziggystar this is a special rule for inheritance of implicits, check out http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/12-the-scala-standard-library.html#predefined-implicit-definitions