# How can I hide my implicit method or disable `LabelledGeneric` for a specific sealed family?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have to use third-party traits which are designed as:

```
trait Super[T]
trait Sub[T] extends Super[T]
```

and I have defined the following method to provide instances for arbitrary sealed families:

```
implicit def subFor[T, Repr](
  implicit
  gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr],
  sg: Lazy[JsonFormat[Repr]]
): Sub[T] = ???
```

but somewhere else in the code, somebody has already defined

```
implicit def superFor[T]: Super[T] = ???
```

for some specific types, e.g. `Option` and a few others.

Actually, I'd like to use the existing implementations instead of
using my `subFor` generic implementation. However, because my
method returns `Sub[T]` and the existing implementation returns
`Super[T]` I can't see any way to define my implementation in
such a way that it is considered lower priority.

How can I block my `subFor` from being called for specific types?
Is there some way to disable `LabelledGeneric` for specific
types, or some priority reducing mechanism that would stop the
compiler from ever looking for my `subFor` if it already sees a
`Super[T]`?

Comment: The old [ambiguous implicits trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15983103/334519) should work here.

Comment: @TravisBrown awesome! Is there a canonical shapeless `Not[T]` that I should use?

Comment: I don't think so—there's type inequality (implemented this way), but IIRC not type class negation.

Comment: Should it be `Sub[T] extends Super[T]`?

Answer (score 2):

If the implicit defs are defined in companion objects, you have to resort to collision-based type computations.  But for "some specific types", the defs are usually not in companion objects of the class (e.g. not on `object Option`).  In this case, you can take advantage of the fact that implicits hide each other within a given namespace.  So you can just

```
implicit def superFor[T]: SomeThrowawayType = ???
```

and their `superFor` won't work any more.  Since you change the return type, it won't collide or anything; it's effectively just gone.  Then you can create your own forwarders at whatever priority level you want that explicitly call their defs.

This does require, however, that you import your stuff *after* theirs (so it shadows theirs).  If this seems too fiddly to be relied upon, you'll have to go for the type computation.