# Scala: "No Type Args" type constraint

Tags: java, scala, type-constraints

Suppose I have a Java class:

```
public class Foo {
    public static <T> T doSomething(Class<T>) { ... }
    public static <T> T doSomething(TypeToken<T>) { ... }
}
```

And now I wish to "Scalafy" it.  That is, create something like:

```
object Bar {
    def doSomething[T]: T
}
```

Apparently, this doesn't compile:

```
def doSomething[T] = Foo.doSomething(classOf[T])
```

And doing something like this requires me to limit `T` to types with no type params:

```
def doSomething[T: ClassTag] = Foo.doSomething(classTag[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]])
```

Now, of course, you can always funnel everything through the `TypeToken` method, but suppose that the `Class` method is cheap and the `TypeToken` method is expensive. The question I wanted to ask is that is there some kind of user-defined type constraint, akin to `=:=` or `<:<`, that I can pass in implicitly to ensure that `T` has no type parameters (more specifically, `classTag[T].runtimeClass` is a `Class[T]` and not some `Class[_ >: T]`)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33529642/2292812