# How to prevent compiler from choosing the least generic type?

Tags: scala, polymorphism, type-inference

I have a method that looks up some storage for an instance of a particular class:

```
def lookup[T >: Null: ClassTag]: T = {
  // Print what class tag we got:
  System.out.println(implicitly[ClassTag[T]].toString);
  null; // details omitted, just return null
}
```

It works well, but the problem is that if I don't provide an explicit type, the compiler chooses `Null` for `T`, and of course it doesn't work then:

```
def print(msg: String) = { /* ... */ }

print(lookup);
```

prints `Null` and of course nothing is found. Clearly the compiler infers the least generic type possible.

If I add an explicit type like

```
print(lookup[String]);
```

it works fine. But this is *very* error-prone. I'd like to either:

1. Let the compiler to always choose the most generic possible type, instead of the least generic possible one. So in `print(lookup)` the most generic possible type is `String`, so I'd like the compiler to infer `String` for `T`. Or
2. Force somehow that an explicit type is always present and issue a compile-time error when I write just something like `print(lookup)`.

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Most generic type is [`AnyRef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128).

2) You could use `=!=` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6929051/406435):

```
scala> def lookup[T >: Null: ClassTag](implicit guard: T =!= Null ): T = {
     |   null; // details omitted, just return null
     | }
lookup: [T >: Null](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T], implicit guard: =!=[T,Null])T

scala> lookup
<console>:11: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method equal in trait LowerPriorityImplicits of type [A]=> =!=[A,A]
 and method nequal in object =!= of type [A, B](implicit same: =:=[A,B])=!=[A,B]
 match expected type =!=[Null,Null]
              lookup
              ^

scala> lookup[String]
res3: String = null
```