# Require user to provide [Type] in Scala's method?

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance

If I write something along the lines of:

```
class A

class B {
  def add[T <: A]() = { ... }
}
```

Then how do I **require** a user to provide the type `T` when he calls `B.add`? These two calls compile:

```
class C extends A

class D extends A {
  val b = new B
  b.add()      // 1.
  b.add[C]()   // 2.
}
```

I'd like `1.` to generate compile-time error instead of defaulting to `b.add[D]()`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Related: [How to prevent compiler from choosing the least generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16425502/1333025)

Comment: @PetrPudlák: How could I forget about that answer! What a shame. It's not related, it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `=!=` evidence from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6929051/406435) to enforce difference between `A` and `T` like this:

```
def add[T <: AnyRef](implicit e: T =!= AnyRef) = null.asInstanceOf[T]

scala> add
<console>:10: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method equal in trait LowerPriorityImplicits of type [A]=> =!=[A,A]
 and method nequal in object =!= of type [A, B](implicit same: =:=[A,B])=!=[A,B]
 match expected type =!=[T,AnyRef]
              add
              ^

scala> add[String]
res1: String = null
```