# Scala type level minus

Tags: scala, types

Is there a way, how to express minus operator on types? I'd like to be able to achieve this:

```
trait A
trait B
type C = A with B
type D = C minus A
// type B == D
```

I know, that this cannot be done directly, but maybe someone was able to express this operator with some clever trick...

--- edit

**Motivation**:

```
trait A
object B extends A
object C extends A
object D extends A
def myMethod(one:A,two:A,three:A) = ???
```

It is only valid to use every type once, so when the user of this method picks `B` for `one` parameter, it is valid to use `C` and `D` in the other parameters...

Comment: http://michid.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/union-types/

Comment: perhaps of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different questions — I'm only answering the use case where you want a call to `myMethod` to fail if you pass the same object twice. For the first four lines, see [Miles Sabin’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944070/390581) to the question that Peter Schmitz linked.

```
trait =!=[A, B]
implicit def neq[A, B]: A =!= B = null
implicit def neqAmbig1[A]: A =!= A = null
implicit def neqAmbig2[A]: A =!= A = null

trait A
object B extends A
object C extends A
object D extends A
def myMethod[A, B, C](one: A, two: B, three: C)(implicit ev1: A =!= B, ev2: A =!= C, ev3: C =!= B) = ???
```

Comment: is there any generic no-macro approach with regards to number of the arguments?

Comment: I'm not knowledgable enough to say a definite no, but AFAIK, no.