# Why has Scala no type-safe equals method?

Tags: scala, equals, equality

Since the inventors highlight *Scala*'s type-safety I don't understand the absence of an equals method on objects (at least from *case classes*) that allows to check the equality only on objects with same type. I'd wish a method `===` that implement this behavior per default. Of course its necessary for Java interoperability to have a method that works with `Any` type but in many cases I want to check only the equality between objects of same type.

#### Why do I need it?

For example I have two case classes and create objects from it

```
  case class Pos(x: Int, y: Int)
  case class Cube(pos: Pos)

  val startPos = new Pos(0, 0)
  val cubeOnStart = new Cube(startPos)
```

and later I need to check the positions several times and write accidentally

```
  if (startPos == cubeOnStart) {
    // this code will never be executed, but unfortunately this compiles
  }
```

but meant

```
  if (startPos == cubeOnStart.pos) {
    // this code can be executed if positions are equal
  }
```

If a method `===` would be available I would use it by intuition.

Is there a good reason or explanation why such a method is missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference might be something you're looking for.

Comment: the problem is addressed in Dotty, see http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/05/06/multiversal-equality.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Equality in Scala is a mess, and the answer to your *why* question (which Stack Overflow isn't really the ideal venue for) is "because the language designers decided Java interoperability trumped doing the reasonable thing in this case".

At least in recent versions of Scala your `startPos == cubeOnStart` will result in a warning stating that comparing values of these different types "will always yield false".

The [Scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) provides the `===` operator you're looking for via a type-safe `Equal` type class. You'd write something like this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

implicit val cubeEqual = Equal.equalA[Cube]
implicit val posEqual = Equal.equalA[Pos]
```

Now `startPos === cubeOnStart` will not compile (which is exactly what we want), but `startPos === cubeOnStart.pos` will, and will return `true`.

Comment: Arguably, Java interop is the reasonable thing _in general_, as it massively increases the size and scope of libraries available. That's a huge consideration for practical languages…

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I understand that for Java interoperability the equals method with argument `Any` is there, but that a type-safe variant is missing seems to be a big gap in the language/library.

Comment: This is now being [considered](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/05/06/multiversal-equality.html) by Martin Odersky

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018, there is [Multiversal Equality](http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/multiversal-equality.html) for Dotty. It needs the developers to define the types for which the equality check makes sense, though. All in all, elegant backwards-compatible solution.