# Pattern match empty ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any special case class for representing an empty `ArrayBuffer` that can be used in pattern matching similar to `Nil` for lists?

Also why this works:

```
scala> collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty == Nil
res11: Boolean = true
```

While this does not:

```
scala> collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer() match { case Nil => 1 }
<console>:8: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Nothing]
```

**UPDATE**

After giving it some thought I presume there is no such a case class. While existence of `Nil` is vital for `List` to work, no special structure of this kind is needed for arrays.

I've found a workaround for empty match check that might work in most cases:

```
collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(2) match { 
  case collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(v, _*) => v * 2
  case _ => 0 
}
```

I first check if array has at least one element and otherwise it should be empty.
Also as it turns out I could just use `ArrayBuffer.isEmpty` instead of pattern match.

Comment: `ArrayBuffer.isEmpty` seems more right for a non-ADT! ...or just `toList` your ArrayBuffer, unless it's too expensive, and work on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jasper-M provided a good answer to your second question (why `==` works but pattern matching fails).

As to your first, there is no equivalent to `Nil` for `ArrayBuffer`. The reason is that `List` is defined using scala's notion of Algebraic Data Types (ADT), while `ArrayBuffer` is not.

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.scala#L1) for `ArrayBuffer`. It's implemented as a regular class, whereas `List` is implemented as an abstract class with two subclasses: a `case object` [Nil](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L419), and a `case class` [::](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L440).

These `case` classes are what allow you to pattern match on `List`. Since there's no equivalent for `ArrayBuffer`, you cannot pattern match.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my own thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty == Nil
res11: Boolean = true
```

The reason this is true can be found by looking at the documentation of the `equals` method:

> true if that is a sequence that has the same elements as this sequence
>   in the same order, false otherwise

For instance:

```
scala> val buffer = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Int]
buffer: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer()

scala> buffer.append(4)

scala> buffer == List(4)
res1: Boolean = true
```

So that has nothing to do with pattern matching.

Comment: By the way, [some people out there think that scala lacks notion of *type safe equals*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742527/why-has-scala-no-type-safe-equals-method), which will not allow things like op's example, or, say, `1 == 1.0`

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought I presume there is no such a case class. While existence of `Nil` is vital for `List` to work, no special structure of this kind is needed for arrays.

I've found a workaround for empty match check that might work in most cases:

```
collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(2) match { 
  case collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(v, _*) => v * 2
  case _ => 0 
}
```

I first check if array has at least one element and otherwise it should be empty.

Comment: This answer might be more appropriate as an edit to your original question. Also, why are you not using `ArrayBuffer#isEmpty`?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question instead. Wow, did not know `ArrayBuffer` has such a property.