# Scala implicit TypeTag not propagating correctly (implicit type is Nothing)

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit

I'm using scala's 2.10 TypeTags extensively in my code and I observe some behavior related to type inference that I do not understand.

Example code:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object BugDemo extends App {
  def printType[T <: AnyRef : TypeTag]() : T = { 
    println(typeOf[T]); 
    null.asInstanceOf[T]; 
  }

  case class Foo()

  var foo1 = printType[Foo]()
  var foo2 : Foo = printType[Foo]()
  var foo3 : Foo = printType()
}
```

Now I expect it to print `Foo` 3 times, but in reality I get (scala 2.10.3):

```scala
BugDemo.Foo
BugDemo.Foo
Nothing
```

What's wrong with my code? Why doesn't scala want to pass a proper type tag for my `T` in `foo3`?

Comment: Do you know that you've created an impossible method, method that actually **returns `Nothing`**?! It's sooo weird!

Comment: @senia yup its weird. Sounds like a compiler bug to me. Do you think I should file it?

Comment: I don't know. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/_wGhZcCqur8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is nothing wrong.

With type parameter not specified scala compiler takes the most concrete type. In case of `printType()` it's `Nothing` (the bottom type in scala type hierarchy).

Since `Nothing` is subtype of `Foo` your code is valid:

```
var foo3 : Foo = printType[Nothing]()
```

Funny thing is that with `var foo3 : Nothing = printType[Nothing]()` or even with `printType[Nothing]()` you'll get a `NullPointerException`:

```
scala> var foo3 : Nothing = printType[Nothing]()
Nothing
java.lang.NullPointerException

scala> printType[Nothing]()
Nothing
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

You can't get an instance of `Nothing`, but your code (`var foo3 : Foo = printType[Nothing]()`) works due to the type erasure. It looks like a scala bug that can't be fixed.

Comment: I see, though this doesn't make my life easier. Is there any way for me to force correct type inference here without introducing any parameters? Maybe introduce lower bound? Unfortunately `T > Nothing` doesn't exist.

Or is it at least possible to fail compilation on Nothing somehow?

Comment: @mikea: you could [enforce type difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference) like this: `def printType[T <: AnyRef : TypeTag]()(implicit d: T =!= Nothing): T`, but it will just force compiler to fail on `printType()` with no type parameter specified.

Comment: `Nothing` is the bottom of type lattice, not the top. The top is `Any`.

Comment: =!= is neat, but it requires importing it into every call site. Any other solutions?

Comment: @RandallSchulz: thank you, fixed. I can't understand and remember it: if type hierarchy is a tree why the root (`Any`) is on top?

Comment: @senia turns out that top answer in =!= doesn't work for Nothing case at all. The second one works, and you are right no import is needed. If only I was now able to say that this function's implicit arguments are whatever is needed by its body...

Comment: Scala's type system forms a full lattice, not merely a tree. Any two types you care to name have both a LUB (most-derived / narrowest common supertype) and GLB (least-derived / widest common sub-type), even if the LUB is `Any` and the GLB is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is the type parameter inferred by scala when one isn't explicitly provided by the caller. I hate (HATE) this default behavior because is leads to all sorts of runtime bugs Nothing is an allowed parameter to everything.

Its much better to enforce that the type parameter should be fully specified at compile-time by [requiring that its not Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403287/possible-to-make-scala-require-a-non-nothing-generic-method-parameter-and-return/41403871#41403871):

```
sealed trait NotNothing[-T] 

object NotNothing {
  implicit object YoureSupposedToSupplyAType extends NotNothing[Nothing]
  implicit object notNothing extends NotNothing[Any] 
}
```

and then:

```
def printType[T : TypeTag : NotNothing]() : T = { ... }
```