# Method signature of function that returns a homogenous tuple?

Tags: scala, types, tuples

Ignoring the idea that a list is a kind of homogenous tuple:

```
scala> def homogeneousPair[T]: (T, T) = (1, 2)
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: T
   def homogeneousPair[T]: (T, T) = (1, 2)
                                     ^
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(2)
required: T
   def homogeneousPair[T]: (T, T) = (1, 2)
                                        ^
```

Is there a way to leverage the type system to enforce homogeneity?

Comment: This is very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference

Comment: For the record (since the accepted answer doesn't make much of an effort to explain itself), the problem with your code is that you're promising a generic method but giving a specific implementation. You _could_ write e.g. `def same[T](p: (T, T)) = p`, and if `same(x)` compiles you know `x` is a homogenous tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object Test {
  type HomogeneousPair[T] = Tuple2[T, T]

  val x: HomogeneousPair[Int] = (1, 2)
}
```

Comment: Makes you wonder why Pair, now deprecated, was hetero.  If I am wearing a pair of shoes, I mean matched shoes, not a sneaker and a loafer.  "Those shoes are not a pair."