# Scala: Lower type bound A without B

Tags: scala

I want to achieve this:

```
implicit def aConvertable(obj: A): B = new B(obj)
implicit def aConvertableWithoutB[T <: A without B](obj: T): C = new C(obj)
```

What is the correct way to say: "A without B"?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need this.

Comment: You might find some hints or clues here (and it's a fascinating read!): http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/

Comment: Or even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that B is a subtype of A. The trick is to introduce an implicit "AllowedConversion" trait that works for all A's, and then two implicit instances for B that have the same type, so that they're ambiguous for B:

```
object Foo {

  trait A
  class B(a: A) extends A

  class C(a: A) 


  class AllowedConversion[T]

  implicit def allowedForAs[T<:A] = new AllowedConversion[T]
  implicit def contradictoryForBs[T <: B] = new AllowedConversion[T]
  implicit def contradictoryForBs2[T <: B] = new AllowedConversion[T]


  implicit def aConvertable(obj: A): B = new B(obj)
  implicit def aConvertableWithoutB[T <: A](obj: T)(implicit allowed: AllowedConversion[T]): C = new C(obj)

  // error!
  // new B(new A{}):C

  // ok!
  new A{}:C

}
```