# Is it possible in Scala to specify a constraint on a generic type τ such that τ <: σ ∧ τ ≠ σ?

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have a type:

```
class σ
```

Now I want to define a type:

```
class υ[τ <: σ]
```

With the additional requirement that τ ≠ σ.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Miles Sabin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944070/2650437) :

```
trait =!=[A, B]

implicit def neq[A, B] : A =!= B = null
implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =!= A = null
implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =!= A = null
```

then :

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> class B[C <: A](implicit ev: C =!= A)
defined class B

scala> class D extends A
defined class D

scala> new B[D]()       // OK, D is a subtype of A
res4: B[D] = B@4d8c463c


scala> new B[A]()       // Error, A =:= A
<console>:15: error: ambiguous implicit values:
   both method neqAmbig1 of type [A]=> =!=[A,A]
   and method neqAmbig2 of type [A]=> =!=[A,A]
   match expected type =!=[A,A]

scala> class E
defined class E

scala> new B[E]()       // Error, E is not a subtype of A
<console>:15: error: type arguments [E] do not conform to class B's type parameter bounds [C <: A]
```

Comment: Is A =!= B equal to =!=[A, B]? And can we use A AnyName B instead of AnyName[A, B]?

Comment: @cloud Yes, `A =!= B` is the same as `=!=[A, B]`; note that this is similar to the two syntaxes for calling methods, the "operator" syntax and the "normal" syntax.

Comment: It would be nice if it were possible to get a better error message than the confusing "ambiguous implicit values".

Comment: @Jesper Indeed. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6806 and https://github.com/typelevel/scala/pull/32