# Evidence that types are not equal in Scala

Tags: scala, types, shapeless, implicits

Is there any way to constraint a method so that it only makes sense if two types are proved *not* to be equal?

```
trait Something[A, B] {
  // I can only be called if type A is the same as type B
  def ifEqual(implicit ev: A =:= B)

  // Now I cannot be called if type A is proven to be the same as type B
  def ifNotEqual(implicit ev: A ??? B)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. From [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L36),

```
// Type inequalities
trait =:!=[A, B] 

implicit def neq[A, B] : A =:!= B = new =:!=[A, B] {}
implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =:!= A = ???
implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =:!= A = ???
```

Comment: As always, amazing type-fu!

Comment: This must be a duplicate, except it's so cool Miles stepped in to answer it.  It's like that scene from Annie Hall when Marshall McLuhan shows up in the movie line.  "If life were only like this!"

Comment: Defintely a duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference.