# Is ambiguous implicit value the only way we want to make the error existed in compilation time

Tags: scala, type-safety, shapeless

```
trait Foo

trait Bar extends Foo

def doStuff[T <: Foo](x: T)(implicit ev: T =!:= Foo) = x

doStuff(new Foo{}) //ambiguous implicit value
doStuff(new Bar)// successful
```

Implicit resolution is happening on compilation time, so in here I think there may be two implicit value with exactly same type to trigger *ambiguous* stuff.

Right now, I am going to introduce shapeless into the team, my colleagues think this ambiguous implicit is not ideal, and I dont have strong argument about it. Is this only way to do it in order to make type safe in scala. If it is, what can I do to customize the error message ?

**Edit:**

In the shapeless, I want to make the sum of 2 NAT not equal to 7, I can code like this to make compilation fail.

```
def typeSafeSum[T <: Nat, W <: Nat, R <: Nat](x: T, y: W)
         (implicit sum: Sum.Aux[T, W, R], error: R =:!= _7) = x

typeSafeSum(_3, _4)
```

but the error message is ambiguous implicit value, how can I customize the error message ?

Answer (score 7):

A simple type class would be better than a type inequality test in this (and most other) instance(s).

Presumably the reason for wanting to exclude `Foo` is that `Bar` (and its siblings) have some properties which `Foo` lacks. If that's the case then you should create a type class which captures those properties and make that a requirement on the type argument for `doStuff`. You can use Scala's `@implicitNotFound` annotation to make compiler error messages more comprehensible whenever that requirement isn't met.

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "No Props instance for ${T}")
trait Props[T] {
  def wibble(t: T): Double
}

trait Foo
// Note no Props instance for Foo ...

trait Bar extends Foo
object Bar {
  // Props instance for Bar
  implicit def barProps: Props[Bar] = new Props[Bar] {
    def wibble(t: Bar): Double = 23.0
  }
}

def doStuff[T <: Foo](t: T)(implicit props: Props[T]) = props.wibble(t)

scala> doStuff(new Foo {})
<console>:11: error: No Props instance for Foo
              doStuff(new Foo {})
                     ^

scala> doStuff(new Bar {})
res1: Double = 23.0
```

If there aren't any such properties which distinguish `Foo` from `Bar` then you should question your supposition that you need to exclude `Foo` from `doStuff` in the first place.

I'd be delighted if you use shapeless in your project, but you should use `=!:=` (and Scala's own `=:=`) only as a last resort, if at all.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I just edit NAT example from shapeless, how can I customize this error message ? because there is no @annotation.ambiguousImplicit stuff

Comment: That seems to be an fairly different question. Usual SO etiquette is one question per ... question ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In this other question, I posted an answer that adress the issue of getting a better error message: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17047288/1632462

Here's the code:

```
@annotation.implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${A} =!= ${B}.")
trait =!=[A,B]
object =!= {
  class Impl[A, B]
  object Impl {
    implicit def neq[A, B] : A Impl B = null
    implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A Impl A = null
    implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A Impl A = null
  }

  implicit def foo[A,B]( implicit e: A Impl B ): A =!= B = null
}
```

And now you get the error message `error: Cannot prove that Foo =!= Foo`:

```
def doStuff[T <: Foo](x: T)(implicit ev: T =!= Foo) = x
doStuff(new Foo{}) // error: Cannot prove that Foo =!= Foo
doStuff(new Bar)// successful
```

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile adding that to shapeless ... could you send a PR in my direction?

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can put constraint on your `doStuff` method use magnet pattern, which is simply enhanced typeclass, e.g:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar

object DoStuff {
  def doStuff[T](value: StuffMagnet[T]): Unit = value()
}

trait StuffMagnet[T] {
  def apply(): Unit
}

object StuffMagnet {
  implicit def forFoo(foo: Foo): StuffMagnet[Foo] = 
    new StuffMagnet[Foo] {
      def apply(): Unit = ()
    }
}
```

The difference in this case would be that you can't add implicitNotFound annotation for better compile time error message, you'll get a simple type mismatch, like:

```
Test.scala:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Test.Bar
 required: Test.StuffMagnet[?]
  DoStuff.doStuff(new Bar {})
                  ^
one error found
```