# Scala limit function parameters possible types

Tags: scala, types

I have a function taking a parameter that could be of type Int, Long, or any children of AnyVal except Unit, it can also be a String. I would like to explicitly specify that you can only put a value of one of those types as a parameter. I could simply put Any but it would not limit anything.
Is there a concept or feature in Scala that offer this possibility ? If not how would you manage that ? 
For now I am simply managing any exception happening in the function if the type is not compatible.

No code to show really :

```
def myFunction(param: Any) = {...}
```

Comment: Do you also want to allow value classes?

Comment: Also, please post the code you already have so we can better understand.

Comment: I only want to allow a some specific types, among it Int, Long, String...

Comment: What are you doing inside the function? How do you discriminate on the different types?

Comment: This solution might be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6929051/848128

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want a complex type restriction, the usual way to express this is by requiring an implicit helper of a sealed type:

```
sealed trait Helper[T]
object Helper {
  implicit object IntHelper extends Helper[Int] {...}
  implicit object StringHelper extends Helper[String] {...}
  ...
}

def myFunction[T: Helper](t: T) = ...
```

That way `myFunction` can only be called for `T` for which you've defined a `Helper`, and you can express more complicated constraints using "recursive implicits" (implicit functions with implicit parameters).

You can also put the type-specific cases of your function implementation in the `Helper` objects, rather than matching cases in the function, making everything more typesafe.

Comment: Seems good for me, if nobody suggest anything that seems better to me I will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use type-classes to do that:

```
trait CanUse[T]

object CanUse[T] {
  implicit object canUseInt extends CanUse[Int]
  implicit object canUseString extends CanUse[String]
  // etc.
}

def myFunction[T : CanUse](x: T) = { ... }
```

The notation at `myFunction` is syntactic sugar for:

```
def myFunction[T](x: T)(implicit ev: CanUse[T]) = { ... }
```

Therefore, you can see that your implicit `canUse` objects are actually passed to your function. You can therefore add methods to them and implement type-specific behavior.