# Restrict specific type in Scala paramaters?

Tags: scala, types

Sometimes I come across a situation where I specifically want to restrict what can be sent to the function, but accept almost any other kind. Is this possible in Scala? For example, this code deals with my issue at runtime - accepting any type T except Option objects. Could the compiler catch it? Thank you

```
def apply[T:TypeTag](t: T): TaggedOption[T] =
  t match {
    case o: Option[_] =>
      // ensure this can't be created
      throw new Exception("This function doesn't work with Options")
    case other =>
      TaggedOption_(Some(t), PowerTag[T])
  }
```

Comment: No. Why? No. What are you doing? No. *Why?*

Comment: Do you want it to fail on `Option[_]` or also on its supertypes? e.g. if I have `x: Option[_]` and I can circumvent your restriction by casting it up, as in `apply(x: Any)`, is that okay?

Comment: @ChrisMartin In my example this is a factory method creating a scheme I have that's similar to Scala's Option. Anyway, since I don't want to deal with Some(Some(x)) and that kind of thing - that's why I want it to outright reject anything that's already an Option object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to restrict the type parameter:

```
scala> trait <:!<[A, B]
defined trait $less$colon$bang$less

scala> implicit def nsub[A, B] : A <:!< B = null
nsub: [A, B]=> <:!<[A,B]

scala> implicit def nsubAmbig1[A, B >: A] : A <:!< B = ???
nsubAmbig1: [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]

scala> implicit def nsubAmbig2[A, B >: A] : A <:!< B = ???
nsubAmbig2: [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]

scala> def notOption[A](a: A)(implicit ev: A <:!< Option[_]) = a
notOption: [A](a: A)(implicit ev: <:!<[A,Option[_]])A

scala> notOption(1)
res0: Int = 1

scala> notOption(List(""))
res1: List[String] = List("")

scala> notOption(Option(1))
<console>:14: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 of type [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]
 and method nsubAmbig2 of type [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]
 match expected type <:!<[Option[Int],Option[_]]
              notOption(Option(1))
                       ^

scala> notOption(Some(1))
<console>:14: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 of type [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]
 and method nsubAmbig2 of type [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]
 match expected type <:!<[Some[Int],Option[_]]
              notOption(Some(1))
                       ^

scala> notOption(None)
<console>:14: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method nsubAmbig1 of type [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]
 and method nsubAmbig2 of type [A, B >: A]=> <:!<[A,B]
 match expected type <:!<[None.type,Option[_]]
              notOption(None)
                       ^
```

The implicits make the `Option` case ambiguous. For a more detailed explanation on how the code is supposed to work, see the following [thread on scala-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/sXGhnGe4YPs/1XH_qFb9iDQJ).

Comment: And here is the corresponding question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference. Please note that this is not perfect as it only works on the static type, and you can always pass an instance of `Option` whose static type is `Any` or `AnyRef`. In other words, the following compiles fine: `val o: Any = Some(1); notOption(o)`

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is NOT a solution to your question, but a possible solution to your problem.

You could handle Option objects by unwrapping them first.

```
def apply[T:TypeTag](t: T): TaggedOption[T] =
  t match {
    case Some(x) =>
      apply(x)
    case None => TaggedNone // or whatever
    case other =>
      TaggedOption_(Some(t), PowerTag[T])
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you I am aware. The question is more about placing restrictions upon the scala compiler to outright reject various T types