# How to accept all types except Future in definition of method in Scala?

Tags: scala, scalaz, type-systems

```
def withCachedFuture[K, V](key: K)(future: ⇒ Future[V])(implicit cache: Cache[K, Future[V]], ec: ExecutionContext): Future[V] = {
  Option(cache getIfPresent key) match {
    case Some(result) ⇒
      result
    case None ⇒
      val result = future
      cache.put(key, result)

      result recover {
        case e ⇒
          cache.invalidate(key)
          throw e
      }
  }
}

def getCachedOrElsePut[K, V](key: K, default: ⇒ V)(implicit cache: Cache[K, V], system: ActorSystem): V = {
  Option(cache getIfPresent key) match {
    case None ⇒
      val result = default
      cache.put(key, result)
      result
    case Some(v) ⇒ v
  }
}
```

These two methods get data from a cache, and if the data are not found, they store a default value, which is passed to the methods as an argument.

The first method is suitable for only the `Future` type, and the second one is for all types except `Future`. We can pass a `Future` to the `getCachedOrElsePut` method, but the `Future` value might be a `Failure`.

How can I restrict the `getCachedOrElsePut` method to statically accept all types except `Future`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like duplicate for another question: [Restrict specific type in Scala paramaters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182411/restrict-specific-type-in-scala-paramaters)

Using answer from there you can restrict it so:

```
trait <:!<[A, B]
implicit def nsub[A, B] : A <:!< B = null
implicit def nsubAmbig1[A, B >: A] : A <:!< B = ???
implicit def nsubAmbig2[A, B >: A] : A <:!< B = ???
```

and add another implicit argument for `getCachedOrElsePut` as `ev: V <:!< Future[_]`

For details it was recommended to go to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/sXGhnGe4YPs/1XH_qFb9iDQJ)

So you will get compile-time check.
For runtime also I would recommend to add type check of parameter (because method will accept Future casted to Object for example)