# How can I prove that two types have no subtyping relation in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

<sub>*(Note: The motivation for this requires a long and difficult explanation; you can find the full discussion on this [Accord issue](https://github.com/wix/accord/issues/37). It might not even be the right solution to the problem, but I believe the question is interesting in of itself.)*</sub>

I'm looking a way to implement a binary operator such that the behavior depends on the *type* of the right-hand operand: one behavior if it is the same as the left-side operand, different behavior otherwise. As an example:

```
implicit class Extend[T](lhs: T) {
  def testAgainst(rhs: T) = println("same type")
  def testAgainst[U](rhs: U) = println("different type")
}
```

The first overload is more specific than the second, so you would expect an invocation such as `5 testAgainst 10` to trigger the first overload, whereas `5 testAgainst "abcd"` would invoke the second overload. While this makes sense in theory, this will not compile because the erased signature is the same for both overloads.

I've managed to work around this in a way that requires adding a type parameter to the first overload, but that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. A different solution would be to modify the generic overload to require compiler evidence that there is no subtyping relation between the types (the opposite of `=:=`, which unfortunately is not provided by the Scala library).

While it is generally pretty easy to encode subtyping relationships in Scala, I've found no way to encode the *lack* thereof. Is there any way to require that, for the second overload to be a candidate at compile time, neither `T <:< U` or `T >:> U` are true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enforce that two types are different strictly at compile time, then [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference) for you. Using one of the answers that defines `=!=`, we can imagine multiple methods that look like this:

```
implicit class Extend[T](lhs: T) {
  def testAgainst(rhs: T) = println("same type")
  def testAgainst[U](rhs: U)(implicit ev: T =!= U) = println("different type")
}
```

---

We can also do the type test within one method using `TypeTag` quite easily.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

implicit class Extend[T: TypeTag](lhs: T) {
  def testAgainst[U: TypeTag](rhs: U): Boolean = typeOf[T] =:= typeOf[U]
}
```

You could then of course modify it to branch the behavior.

```
scala> 1 testAgainst 2
res98: Boolean = true

scala> 1 testAgainst "a"
res99: Boolean = false

scala> List(1, 2, 3) testAgainst List(true, false)
res100: Boolean = false

scala> List(1, 2) testAgainst List.empty[Int]
res102: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Thanks! I looked for but evidently missed the question you referenced. Unfortunately my problem is a bit more hairy than mere implicit resolution, but the ambiguous implicit trick alone was worth the price of admission :-)

Comment: Also, as long as you don't need to support generic right-hand operands, there's a workable solution here: https://github.com/wix/accord/issues/37#issuecomment-101213060

Unfortunately, in my case that is exactly what I need to do. The runtime reflection solution obviously won't help for that either...

Comment: @TomerGabel Apparently removing the first implicit does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is actually pretty straightforward. Your only real problem is that both your overloads have the same erasure, which is only a problem to the compiler because of the limitations of the underlying JVM. As far as typing is concerned, having those two overloads is perfectly fine.

So all you have to do is to change the signature of one overload in such a way that is functionally equivalent. This can be done using an implicit parameter that will always be found (typically, standard library's `DummyImplicit`) or by adding a dummy parameter with a default value. So either of those is fine (I usually use the first version):

```
def testAgainst[U](rhs: U)(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit) = println("different type")
```

or:

```
def testAgainst[U](rhs: U, dummy: Int = 0) = println("different type")
```

Comment: While useful, this doesn't actually answer the original question (how to implement =!=). I didn't know about DummyImplicit, though, so thanks!

Comment: Well I thought the actual question was about how to "implement a binary operator such that the behavior depends on the type of the right-hand operand: one behavior if it is the same as the left-side operand, different behavior otherwise", which as your example shows can be done through simple overloading (once "fixed", that is, as I'm showing above). From your description is appears that the quest for a working `=!=` operator only stems from your attempt to find an alternative to overloading because you could not make it work. But it **can** work, as I've shown. What did I miss?

Comment: This particular question stems from trying to work around a bigger issue in a Scala-based DSL; what you quoted is essentially the context to the more specific question. Re-reading my question, though, it seems that it was a bit ambiguous about what exactly I'm looking for, so you get your upvote anyways :-)

Comment: As an aside, evidently adding any type-parameterized overload breaks what I was hoping to achieve in the first place (see the Accord bug linked from the question), so at this point I'm pretty sure the broader problem can't really be worked around.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to determine at runtime that there is no subtyping relationship between types based on implicit resolution rules and default implicit values. It can be illustrated by this simple function and its invocations:

```
scala> def checkSubtypes[T, U](implicit ev: T <:< U = null) = ev
checkSubtypes: [T, U](implicit ev: <:<[T,U])<:<[T,U]

scala> checkSubtypes[Int, Long]
res4: <:<[Int,Long] = null

scala> checkSubtypes[Integer, Number]
res5: <:<[Integer,Number] = <function1>
```

If type `T` is not a subtype of some other type `U`, the compiler won't be able to find an implicit value for `T <:< U`, and so the default value will be used, which is `null` in this case.

This, however, would only work at runtime, so it probably does not answer your question exactly, but nevertheless this trick may be useful sometimes.

Comment: As long as you're testing strict subtyping, requiring evidence that T<:<U is also applicable at compile time. I'm actually looking for a different constraint, one that proves that there's no subtyping relation at all (i.e. neither T<:<U nor T>:>U).

Comment: Well, with `(implicit ev1: T <:< U = null, ev2: U <:< T = null)` if both of arguments are `null` at runtime then types are not related.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a neat trick! Too bad you can only evaluate it at runtime. That can probably be worked around with a macro, but since there's a different hack that does work at compile-time (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference as linked by m-z) it seems like overkill.

Comment: @TomerGabel, funny thing is, I only looked at that answer now and it seems that that trick could be adapted to work with subtyping as well - it uses the same `null` default value approach like this one.

Comment: There are multiple options; my favorite so far is leveraging ambiguous implicits. Would never have thought of that in a million years :-)