# Restrict Generic function fun[T] with multiple parameters on higher types on T to be exactly T

Tags: scala

I have the following function

```
def f[T](l:List[T], v:T)
```

this works without errors for

```
f(List(1,2,3), "this is a string")
```

even when T is not same in both parameters. Is it possible to rewrite the function so that the compiler gives me an error when T is not same in both parameters? (I cant rely on the user to explicitly specify the type in function f[Int])

[Apologies for the horrible title]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to prevent type unification out of the box. You could take a look at this SBT plugin: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-ynolub, but IIUC it can only disable LUBing for the whole compiled codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type unification happens only within a parameter list. You can use separate parameter lists, although this only ensures that `v.type <:< T`, not that `v.type =:= T`.

```scala
def f[T](l:List[T])(v:T): List[T] = v :: l

f(List(1,2,3))("this is a string")

Error:(81, 20) type mismatch;
found   : String("this is a string")
required: Int
f(List(1,2,3))("this is a string")
```

Another option is using an implicit, although it requires a type cast:

```scala
def f[T, U](l: List[T], v: U)(implicit ev: T =:= U): List[T] =
  v.asInstanceOf[T] :: l

val l1 = List("a", "b", "c")
val l2: List[Any] = List("a", "b", "c")

val s1 = "d"
val s2: Any = "d"

f(l1, s1) // compiles
f(l2, s2) // compiles
f(l1, s2) // Cannot prove that String =:= Any.
f(l2, s1) // Cannot prove that Any =:= String.
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, Scala handles type classes in such situations by finding the common supertype that could be generalized as T. In your example, you have `Int` and `String` whom common super is `Any`. So `def f[T](l:List[T], v:T): T = v` invoked with `f(List(1, 2, 3), "scala")` yields `Any = "scala"`.

Now, there are several ways you could handle that depending on the desired behaviour. This question contains neat answers for the opposite question (ensuring type difference) [Enforce type difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference) . On the other hand, you could resolve to using `ClassTag` or introducing some implicits that would allow you to distinguish types. Nevertheless, regardless of the approach your method most likely will require following definition `def f[U, T](l: List[U], v: T)` and implement one of the abovementioned type guards.