# Specifying Type Constraint Bound

Tags: scala

Given:

```
sealed trait F
sealed trait K extends F
case object K1 extends K
sealed trait L extends F
case object L1 extends L
```

Using the above hierarchy, how can I define a function that, at compile-time, has a List of type `A` that is either all `K`'s or `L`'s, i.e. the super-type must be either `K` or `L`, but not `F`?

Example:

`f(List(K1, K1))` would compile since the list's super-type is `K`

but

`f(List(K1, L1))` would not since the list's super-type is `F`

Comment: You could use `Either`, though I've never liked its syntax much

Answer (score 1):

You can start with Miles Sabin's answer at [Enforce type difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference/) and adapt:

```
implicit def notSubtype[A, B]: >!>[A, B] = null
implicit def ambig1[A, B >: A]: >!>[B, A] = null
implicit def ambig2[A, B >: A]: >!>[B, A] = null

def f[A >: K with L](xs: List[A])(implicit ev: A >!> F) = xs


f(List(K1, K1)) // compiles

f(List(K1, L1))
[error] /tmp/rendererB0Um6L4t45/src/main/scala/test.scala:23: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both method ambig1 in object Main of type [A, B >: A]=> >!>[B,A]
[error]  and method ambig2 in object Main of type [A, B >: A]=> >!>[B,A]
[error]  match expected type >!>[F,F]
[error]   f(List(K1, L1))
[error]    ^
```