# Scala 2.11.8 type tags not always properly generated by the compiler

Tags: scala

Can someone explain to me (or redirect to resources) why in this particular case the type tag is not "properly" generated:

```
class A(s: Seq[_]*)

def toto[T: TypeTag](p: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
  println(typeTag[T].tpe)
  p
}

val data = Seq( ("a", "a") )
val x = data.map(_._1)
new A(
  toto(x),
  toto(data.map(_._2)),
  toto[String](data.map(_._2))
)

// output:
// java.lang.String
// Any
// String
```

As far as I understand, it seems that as my class `A` takes "untyped" (well with existential types) sequences, then the compiler does not bother generate the proper type tag when not required explicitly (though it does know the type of `data.map(_._2)` it still uses `TypeTag[Any]`... ). But it looks quite strange and I wondered if there was a more scientific explanation to this phenomenom.

Also, how can I force the compiler to generate a proper `TypeTag[String]` even if I don't want to create special variable (like this `x` variable above)?

Comment: `toto[String](data.map(_._2))` forces it to take the `TypeTag[String]`. By the way: same happens in 2.12.4.

Comment: Yep it does, though it's a bit weird that would should specify it as the compiler knows the information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice problem! I have an explanation, but I am not certain it's right (80%, let's say).

As very often with Scala type inference question, you need to be aware of expected types. In this case, all arguments of `new A` are typed with expected type `Seq[_]`, which is the same as `Seq[Any]` because of covariance. So:

1. `toto(data.map(_._2))` is typed with expected type `Seq[Any]`; `data.map(_._2)` is typed with expected type `Seq[Any]`. The signature of `Seq#map` is

   ```
   def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[A], B, That]): That
   ```

   so `That` is inferred based on the expected type and a suitable implicit `bf` is found. I am not actually sure if `B` is inferred to `String` or `Any`, but it probably doesn't matter.
2. In the `val x = data.map(_._1)`, there is no expected type so `B` is inferred to `String`, an implicit `bf` is found based on `A` and `B` and then `That` is inferred from the complete type of `bf`.
3. `toto(x)` is typed with expected type `Seq[Any]`; `x` is typed with expected type `Seq[Any]`, but it already has type `Seq[String]` and the expected type doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, it would make sense indeed, but then I do not quite understand why it fails also with `data.map(_._2.asInstanceOf[String])`. In this case, `_._2` is typed with `(String, String) => String` - enforced. And so it should fall back in your 2. explanation would'nt it, as the typing is explicit and expected type could be forgotten?

Comment: Think it could be because really you have two parameters, second is implicit `TypeTag[Class]` where `Class` is resolved based on expected `Any`. So later evaluation of how `Seq` typed based on `map` inners will not affect whole type `T`

Comment: It's more that `map` has two type parameters. I've edited the answer. (Though `_._2.asInstanceOf[String]` shouldn't work according to the previous version, `(_._2): ((String, String)) => String` should and still doesn't.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend answer of @AlexeyRomanov by possible solution how to force compiler to evaluate specific type:

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference) I took idea for forcing type difference:

```
sealed class =!=[A,B]
trait LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def equal[A]: =!=[A, A] = sys.error("should not be called")
}
object =!= extends LowerPriorityImplicits {
  implicit def nequal[A,B](implicit same: A =:= B = null): =!=[A,B] =
    if (same != null) sys.error("should not be called explicitly with same type")
    else new =!=[A,B]
}
```

Now we can add limitation for parameter to `toto`:

```
class A(s: Seq[_]*)

def toto[T: TypeTag](p: Seq[T])(implicit guard: T =!= Any): Seq[T] = {
  println(typeTag[T].tpe)
  p
}

val data = Seq(("a", "a"))
val x = data.map(_._1)

new A(
  toto(x),
  toto(data.map(_._2)),
  toto[String](data.map(_._2))
)
```

And output I have

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.String
String
```

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately it fails (at compile-time) if we do need an `Any`, e.g. with `toto(Seq("1", 2))`. I don't want to consider `Any` as an explicit error, just avoid it when it's not the expected type. I'll try to play with you code though see if I can work something around with it. Thanks

Comment: @Vince.Bdn With =!= I break correctness of check for Any as expected type. I'm not sure, that you can solve it by generified function (case which ok with Any will force to cast to `Any` instead of concrete class). But with one class limit you can introduce the only additional method for this specific case, instead of having problems with bunch of cases. But would be nice to know if you find generified solution