# Scala Generics, exclude type

Tags: scala

I need to have a function like:

`def foobar[A](cb: Int => A)`

I would like to check that `A` is not a `Future`.

Is this possible?

@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez this is my code based on your link:

```
def closeOnExit[A <: {def close() : Unit}, B](closeable: A)
                                                (cb: A => B)
                                                (implicit e: B =!= Future[_]): B = {
   try {
      cb(closeable)
   } finally {
      closeable.close()
   }
}
```

No error was generated with: `closeOnExit(new FileOutputStream("deleteme.txt")) {is => Future.successful(1)}`

On the case of:

```
def foobar[A, B](a:A, b:B)(implicit e: A =!= B): (A, B) = (a, b)
foobar(1, 2)
```

You already find an error

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: And how do you do it?

Comment: Please specify,  whether this should be a compile time or runtime check.  Best if you show an example and describe expected error

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforce type difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference)

Comment: Such a problem is usually just a symptom of an underlying systematic problem. Can you please specify some details, maybe show an example why this check is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution

```
  sealed class IsNotFuture[A]

  object IsNotFuture {
    // the fact that we have 2 implicit functions for type Future will fail to compile
    implicit def isFuture1[B <: Future[_]]: IsNotFuture[B] = ???
    implicit def isFuture2[B <: Future[_]]: IsNotFuture[B] = ???

    // all the rest compile
    implicit def isNotFuture[B]: IsNotFuture[B] = new IsNotFuture[B]
  }
```

Comment: Lovely hack! :)

Comment: It's a big hack :) but I found a very well hidden bug with it :o

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Scala_Generics_Excelude_Type {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      new Scala_Generics_Excelude_Type[Int].cb(i => 1) // ok

      new Scala_Generics_Excelude_Type[String].cb(i => "1") // ok

      new Scala_Generics_Excelude_Type[Future[String]].cb(i => null) 
                                       // Exception: No future please

   }
}

class Scala_Generics_Excelude_Type[T: TypeTag] {
   def cb(cb: Int => T) = {
      if (typeOf[T].typeSymbol == typeOf[Future[Any]].typeSymbol) 
                throw new Exception("No future please")
   }
}
```

UPDATE 2018-11-25

is needed:

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value`

Comment: Sory, Hartmut. My solution gives you compilation error.