# How can I exclude a specific type from a TypeClass resolution?

Tags: scala, typeclass, type-constraints

I would like to provide a `ToCondition` operation for most types, but not for strings. (This is when porting a Javascript code, where the non-null and non-zero test is done very often and it is tedious to rewrite all such tests to proper comparison). It is easy to do this so that I receive an error runtime:

```
trait ToCondition[T] {
  def apply(x: T): Boolean
}
implicit object ToConditionInt extends ToCondition[Int] {
  override def apply(x: Int) = x != 0
}
implicit object ToConditionString extends ToCondition[String] {
  override def apply(x: String) = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot use String as a condition")
}
implicit object ToConditionAnyRef extends ToCondition[AnyRef] {
  override def apply(x: AnyRef) = x != null
}

def toCondition[T: ToCondition](a: T): Boolean = implicitly[ToCondition[T]].apply(a)

toCondition(1) // true

toCondition(null:AnyRef) // false

toCondition("") // throws runtime
```

Can this constraint be expressed somehow so that I get the error compile-time instead?

Comment: Just don't implement a typeclass instance for `String`... No? Or do you want to protect clients from implementing `ToConditionString[String]`?

Comment: As I have implemented it for `AnyRef`, it is implemented for `String` as well, as `String` is `AnyRef`.

Comment: I have found similar questions meanwhile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447357/scala-generics-exclude-type

Comment: @MilesSabin showed exactly how he implemented `=:!=` in shapeless. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944070/8990329

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use **generalized type constraint** with the condition, that will never be true, like `String =:= Nothing`:

```
implicit def ToConditionString(implicit ev: String =:= Nothing) = new ToCondition[String] {
  override def apply(x: String) = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot use String as a condition")
}
```

Then

```
toCondition("")
```

fails at compile time with:

> could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type ToCondition[String]

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use shapeless then use type inequality `=:!=`. Here is the version raising compile error for `String`:

```
import shapeless._

trait ToCondition[T] {
  def apply(x: T): Boolean
}
implicit object ToConditionInt extends ToCondition[Int] {
  override def apply(x: Int) = x != 0
}
implicit object ToConditionString extends ToCondition[String] {
  override def apply(x: String) = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot use String as a condition")
}
implicit object ToConditionAnyRef extends ToCondition[AnyRef] {
  override def apply(x: AnyRef) = x != null
}

//Note the implicit value here
def toCondition[T: ToCondition](a: T)(implicit ev: T =:!= String) : Boolean = implicitly[ToCondition[T]].apply(a)

def main(args : Array[String]) {
  toCondition(1) // true

  toCondition(null:AnyRef) // false

  toCondition("") // compile error
}
```

Comment: I think I can use shapeless, or if not, I can perhaps extract the `=:!=` from it.

Comment: @Suma Probably you can take it. Unfortunately I'm not yet closely familar with `shapeless` internals so it would required to take `=:!=`, also implicitis `implicit def neq[A, B] : A =:!= B = new =:!=[A, B] {} implicit def neqAmbig1[A] : A =:!= A = unexpected implicit def neqAmbig2[A] : A =:!= A = unexpected` and probably something more...