# Scala: type inference problem for either.joinRight

Tags: scala, type-inference, typechecking, type-constraints

I have the following types:

```
trait A
trait A1 extends A
trait A2 extends A
```

Standard Scala's Either has the following method:

```
def joinRight[A1 >: A, B1 >: B, C](implicit ev: B1 <:< Either[A1, C]): Either[A1, C]
```

which allows me to simplify nested Either types.

If I have the following two values:

```
val x: Either[A, Either[A, Int]] = Right(Right(1))
val y: Either[A1, Either[A2, Int]] = Right(Right(1))
```

I can call `joinRight` on x just fine and it gives me an instance of `Either[A, Int]`, but if I call joinRight on y, I will get:

> Error: Cannot prove that Either[A1,Int] <:< scala.util.Either[A2,C].
>   x.joinRight

which makes sense since either is: `Either[+A, +B]`

Now if I were to manually pass the type parameters, ie:

```
x.joinRight[A, Either[A, Int], Int]
```

it would work and give me an `Either[A, Int]`. It is quite disappointing that it can't infer it.

Now I have the following alternative implementation which looks like:

```
def joinRightAlt[AA, BB](implicit ev1: B <:< Either[AA, BB], ev2: A <:< AA): Either[AA, BB]
```

which also suffers from the same problem. ie it handles x ok but not y.

Three questions:

- How are the two implementations different for the compiler? is there much difference in terms of the work the compiler has to do to check the type constraints?
- Why does the alternative implementation fail to find the right `EE` and `AA` instances?
- Can we really not have yet another implementation that can handle `y`? is this going to be possible/any easier in Dotty?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to provide all parameters is type ascription:

```
y.joinRight : Either[A, Int]
// res: Either[A, Int] = Right(1)
```

Which is equivalent to assign it to a variable with explicit type, like:

```
val yy: Either[A, Int] = y.joinRight
// yy: Either[A, Int] = Right(1)
```

---

However, if you really want it to be automatically inferred, you can use this extension method.
The trick is, to have both types *(`A1` & `A2`)* in scope. And, force the compiler to find the **LUB** of both types at once.

```
implicit class EitherOps[A1, A2, B](private val e: Either[A1, Either[A2, B]]) extends AnyVal {
  def joinRightAlt[AA](implicit ev: (A1, A2) <:< (AA, AA), f1: A1 => AA, f2: A2 => AA): Either[AA, B] =
    e match {
      case Left(a1)        => Left(f1(a1))
      case Right(Left(a2)) => Left(f2(a2))
      case Right(Right(b)) => Right(b)
    }
}

val x: Either[A, Either[A, Int]] = Right(Right(1))
val y: Either[A1, Either[A2, Int]] = Right(Right(1))
val y1: Either[A1, Either[A2, Int]] = Left(new A1 {})
val y2: Either[A1, Either[A2, Int]] = Right(Left(new A2 {}))

x.joinRightAlt
// res: Either[A, Int] = Right(1)

y.joinRightAlt
// res: Either[A, Int] = Right(1)

y1.joinRightAlt
// res: Either[A, Int] = Left(...)

y2.joinRightAlt
// res: Either[A, Int] = Left(...)
```

*(Keep in mind, that in the worst case, this method will infer **Any** for `AA`)*.

Comment: cool. to enforce the widened type not being `Any` you can use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909053/enforce-type-difference

Comment: Because `A2` is not *<:<* of `A1`, which was your case. Your problem was that there were already two different types, and you needed the compiler to compute the **LUB** between them.

Comment: Yes. The question is, why can't the compiler infer the lowest upper bound?

Comment: @Mathsnoob On the standard definition, is because it expects the **A** of the inner either, to be a subtype of firs one. On your attempt, is the opposite, you expect the first to be a subtype of the second. But for `y` neither were the case, they both were unrelated types. That is why my solution has three types, _`A1`, `A2` & `AA`,_ And, using the little trick of the tuple, I force the compiler to compiler to compute the **LUB**. On other words, the problem was that the compiler was not trying to compute the **LUB**, instead of why it wasn't able to.

Comment: "On your attempt, is the opposite, you expect the first to be a subtype of the second. " The way I understand it, the second type can be understood by the compiler to be the supertype. In the sense that when you feed a `Dog` to a method that expects an `Animal`, it "see"s it as an `Animal`, so I was expecting `A2` to be seen as `A` which I guess you're saying won't happen.

Comment: @Mathsnoob It could see it like that, you are correct in that sense. That is what the **type ascription** would do. But, in the case of the extension method, it already knows the type, and there is nothing forcing the compiler to do the relationship.